# DNS Suffix List is getting weird on Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, configuration, dhcp

I had a look on my Windows Server 2022 template and figure out the following things:

- If I run ipconfig /all, i can see there's 'test.local' as Global Suffix Search List and there's gael-test.net as interface specific suffix search list.
- Then, if i look at my DNS configuration from GUI, it seems that DNS suffixes for this connection is having Global DNS suffix.
  [image]

After some researches and tests, it seems that the interface specific suffix search list value is set at DhcpDomainSearchList value

[image]

My question are **which value is the real connection-specific DNS suffix ? does the global suffix list is superseeding the connection specific settings ?**